# Returning array of custom PSObjects from Powershell class

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I have a powershell class that has method that can return an array of custom PSObjects, though I'm not sure how to define the method so that it won't complain. ie

```
class ThisIsAClass {
    MethodReturnsArray() {
        $thisArray = @()
        for ($i=0; $i -lt $total; $i++) {
            $item = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
            $item | Add-Member MemberType -NoteProperty -Name ID -Value i
            $item | Add-Member MemberType -NoteProperty -Name Text -Value "a"
        }
        return $thisArray
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare a return type for the `MethodReturnsArray()` method. You can assign the output from the `for` loop directly to `$thisArray`:

```
class ThisIsAClass {
    [array]MethodReturnsArray([int]$total) {
        $thisArray = for ($i=0; $i -lt $total; $i++) {
            $item = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
            $item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ID -Value $i
            $item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Text -Value "a"
            $item
        }
        return $thisArray
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, array was the keyword I was missing. I tried `[@()]`. I'll accept when the timer lets me :) Thanks!

Comment: Is `[array]` preferable/different in this case from `[object[]]`?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Good question. From a performance perspective (I would assume), `[object[]]` or `[psobject[]]` is possibly slightly faster, but I find `[array]` easier to read